# I am trying to make a bot on Reddit but python just gave me a long error

Tags: python, bots

So I'm trying to program a Reddit reply bot to simply moderating and i got pretty far into it but then when testing the code python gave me a long error that I don't understand. I haven't tried fixing it much because my skill on python is very limited so I have no idea what to do.

```
import praw



userAgent = 'Recomend Bot 0.1'

cID = 'rz8Gh2k8RS-NRA'

cSC= '9FR8Balfkd0OcgiKVosMSqAP2YM'

userN = ''

userP =''

numFound = 0

reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent, client_id=cID, client_secret=cSC, username=userN, password=userP)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('empfehlen_testen') 

bot_phrase = 'Test Reply 177013' 

keywords = {'test', 'Test', 'recomendation'} 

for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10): 

    n_title = submission.title.lower() 

for i in keywords: 

    if i in n_title: 

        numFound = numFound + 1

print('Bot replying to: ') 

print("Title: ", submission.title)

print("Text: ", submission.selftext)

print("Score: ", submission.score)

print("---------------------------------")

print('Bot saying: ', bot_phrase)

print()

submission.reply(bot_phrase)

if numFound == 0:

    print()

print("Sorry, didn't find any posts with those keywords, try again!")

#credit for code goes to Phrynk for code all I did was get it to work on my coumputer
```

That got working somehow and then this error message popped up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\RedditBot\reddit_bot.py", line 26, in <module>
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10): #this views the top 10 posts in that subbreddit
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\RedditBot\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 52, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\RedditBot\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 62, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\RedditBot\praw\reddit.py", line 446, in get
    data = self.request("GET", path, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\RedditBot\praw\reddit.py", line 581, in request
    method, path, data=data, files=files, params=params
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 185, in request
    params=params, url=url)
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 116, in _request_with_retries
    data, files, json, method, params, retries, url)
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 101, in _make_request
    params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 35, in call
    kwargs['headers'] = set_header_callback()
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 145, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 328, in refresh
    password=self._password)
  File "C:\Users\Dillon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 142, in _request_token
    payload.get('error_description'))
prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request
```

Comment: I hope this not your real client secret. It is meant to be secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request`

means there was a problem authenticating the user.

Remember that the username is your reddit's account name, not the bot's name.

Comment: I feel very stupid I put the wrong password in thanks

Comment: No problem haha, it happens